# Theming custom block in twig file and render variables

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I created a custom block and I'm trying to render it in twig file. The file gets used, as I can see its output, but my variable 'my_variable' defined in the block is not rendered:

in CustomBlock.php

```
public function build() {
    $build = [];

    $build['custom_block'] = [
      '#my_variable' => 'abcdef',
      '#theme' => 'custom_block',
    ];

    return $build;
}
```

in my_module.module:

```
function my_module_theme() {
  return [
    'custom_block' => [
      'template' => 'custom-block',
    ],

  ];
}
```

in custom-block.twig.html:

```
<div>{{ my_variable }}</div>
```

-> The twig file gets used and the div is shown, but the variable is empty/is not rendered.

Comment: Looks like you're forgetting some stuff in my_module.module as CustomBlock.php. Model your module after this: https://github.com/ericski/Drupal-8-Module-Theming-Example

Answer (score 3):

You probably just need to define the available variables:

```
function my_module_theme() {
  return [
    'custom_block' => [
      'template' => 'custom-block',
      'variables' => ['my_variable' => ''],
    ],

  ];
}
```

You'll need to rebuild caches for the change to be picked up.